# unable to get the details on the x-axis using plot method in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline
poll_df=pd.read_csv('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv')
poll_df.plot(x='End Date',y=['Obama','Romney','Undecided'],linestyle='',marker='o')
```

I am getting only 'End Date' written below the x-axis, but i want all the dates present inside the column End date to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the dtype of End Date, End Date in poll_df was a string, converting it to datetime dtype allows pandas plot to correctly format the x-axis with the labels:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline
poll_df=pd.read_csv('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv')
poll_df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(poll_df['End Date'])
poll_df.plot(x='End Date',y=['Obama','Romney','Undecided'],linestyle='',marker='o')
```

Output:

[image]

OR you can use `parse_dates` parameter in read_csv:

```
poll_df=pd.read_csv('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv', 
                     parse_dates=['End Date'])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it worked.But what is parse_dates doing here?

Comment: [Per Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) it calls pd.to_datetime on that column.